# My laptop keyboard doesnot work in GRUB 2.0.2 ! Arrow keys not working in GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, grub2, ubuntu-18.04

Arrow keys does not work in GRUB menu. So i get redirected to UBUNTU 18.0.4 Login page after 10s. I could not find any solution for this problem as the people generally have problem with their usb keyboard . Just need help.

Comment: These problems may not be related, but hours apart, another similar keyboard problem was posted: [Ultra Fast Mode disables keyboard input during GRUB](https://superuser.com/q/1455364/364367).  Any chance you're using UEFI Ultra Fast Mode?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = <kbd>↓</kbd> to select your boot entry.

More key-bindings are described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137326/332764).

Comment: The keyboard is disabled during GRUB .... so no keys work!